# Intellij Live Template Dynamic Text

Tags: intellij-idea, live-templates

I'm trying to create a "dynamic" Live Template for PyCharm and am hitting a road block (I'm able to create simple templates with variable insertion, no problem). I'm beginning to believe that what I'm trying to accomplish may not be possible. I'm not tied to Groovy Script, but it looks to be the most promising alternative to what I'm trying to accomplish. I'm not able to provide a minimal, reproducible example beyond a simple description.  Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

- Whatever is typed after hitting <kbd>TAB</kbd> and before hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> is passed to the template, formatted and written back to the Editor. My goal is to have the resulting string be a specified length, but that's less important for the time being. It's really more about how to get keyboard input *to* the template and back out again.

For example:

"blk" <kbd>TAB</kbd> "Hello world" <kbd>Enter</kbd> becomes 
`# ==================== Hello world ====================`

Is this possible with Live Templates?

EDIT: To be clear, the question here is on how to *reformat the typed input* and return the formatted input to the output of the template. For example, using the above -- have the resulting "Hello world" line always be 80 characters long.

EDIT2: converting previous comment to an answer to close the loop on this question. Happy to reopen if new information comes to light.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have confirmed with Jet Brains that the thing I'm specifically trying to accomplish--***dynamically formatting typed input to a live template***--is not possible within the current IDE (as of version 2020.3).

Instead, they suggest it will require a custom plugin with specific features related to `com.intellij.codeInsight.template.postfix.templates.PostfixTemplate.`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be possible with such a template:

```
# ==================== $MY_TEXT$ ====================
```

Where `$MY_TEXT$` is just an empty custom user [template variable](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/template-variables.html).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer the question. Unfortunately, this doesn't get to the heart of the question. As I noted, I'm able to construct templates with variable insertion.  What I am looking to do is to format the resulting output to meet the needs of the circumstance (for example, ensuring that the output is always 80 characters long or converting a float to an int.)  Unfortunately, your suggestion doesn't do that.  I'll adjust the question to make that more clear.  Thanks again. Cheers.